# Using Microsoft's Text Object Model in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, richtextbox

In one of my Access applications, I want the user to be able to Strike Through words in textboxes. The textboxes have Rich Text enabled now, where one can Bold, Underline, change color, etc, but Strike Through is unavailable.

I was thinking that the Text Object Model is the way to go, but cannot find examples of it, with code written in vba, used anywhere.

I have referenced the Text Object Model (tom) in my app. But then, I am unable to set an object reference, say, to a sentence that has been selected with the mouse.

Is there anyone out there that knows or can show me:

1. Do textboxes, either "regular" or ActiveX, have hooks in them that allow access to them using the tom?
2. If textboxes in Access do not have this capability, are there other ways I can get Strike Through functionality in the entries?
3. Where are there vba examples that can help me with this?

Thanks so much for your input
v/r,
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with TOM, and I'm not sure the RTF editor can handle strikethrough at all - at least the number of questions regarding this implies so. Instead, I offer a workaround:

```
Private Sub btnStrikethrough_Click()
    Me.Field1.Value = StrikeThrough(Me.Field1.Value)
End Sub

Function StrikeThrough(Text As String) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(Text)
        StrikeThrough = StrikeThrough & ChrW(822) & Mid(Text, i, 1)
    Next i
End Function
```

This is perhaps too blunt for your need, but it will strike through your text. It does so by inserting U+0336 (COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY) before every character, making the combined result visible. If you have other formatting, it will destroy it, but I think that can be handled with some parsing.